# Killing Homology classes in 'controlled' way à la in Postnikov tower

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $(X, x)$ be some 'nice' pointed topological space - e.g. a CW complex - and $[\alpha] \in \pi_n(X,x) $ some nontrivial homotopy class represented by a map $\alpha: S^n \to X$. Then there is a standard way to 'kill' this class $[\alpha]$ by modifying the space $X$ appropriately attatching a $D^{n+1}$-ball to $X$ along $\alpha$ forcing $\alpha$ to contract to a single point.

One obtains then a new space $X':= X \cup_{\alpha} D^{n+1}$ together with natural inslusion $\iota_X: X \to X'$. which induces maps $\iota_k: \pi_k(X,x) \to \pi_k(X',x)$ on homology groups which are isomorphisms for $k < n$ and surjective for $k = n$ with $i_n([\alpha])=0$. That's why this modification can be also called 'controlled killing' a homotopy class. 'Controlled' because up all $n > k$ homotopy groups not change. Higher homotopy groups on the other hand may change in highly nontrivial way, but that's 'the price we have to pay.' This is one of the main ingredients how the trunicated groups of Postnikov tower are constructed.

*Question:* Is it also possible to perform in similar manner a modification of $X$ but now with the goal to kill a homology class $[\beta] \in H_n(X,x)$ is similar 'controlled' way, ie by not to destroy 'too much' stucture of the homology group like in case above with homology.

More precisely I'm looking for a way to find a construction $m: X \to X'$ modyfying $X$ in the way that the induced maps on $m_k: H_k(X,x) \to H_k(X',x)$ such that $m_k$ are isomorphisms, $m_n$ is surjective and kills $[\beta]$.

Can it be done in a similar manner like for homotopy groups? The problem: Every homotopy class $[\alpha]$ can be represented by a map $\alpha: S^k \to X$ which can be killed by attatching geometrically a $D^{n+1}$ ball to $X$. In contract a class $[\beta] \in H_n(X,x)$ is a less geometrical object; it is represented by a *formal sum* of $n$-simplices $\sigma: D^n \to X$  with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients, modulo boundaries. So I not see how previous strategy could be applied here.

Comment: Perhaps something like representing the class as a map $K\rightarrow X$ for some complex $K$ and then attaching the cone $CK$ along that.

Comment: @Thorgott: yes was exactly the intuition I had in mind firstly pondering about this problem, but I think there is a serious gap. Say $[\beta]\in H_n(X)$ is a class represented by some chain $\sum_{i} a_i \sigma_i^n$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\sigma_i^n: D^n \to X$ where only finitely many $a_i$ are non-zero. The problem is that $\sum_{i} a_i \sigma_i^n$ is a 'purely algebraic object', ie due to coefficients we cannot 'naturally' associate a complex to it. We can for example associate a complex to it's support, ie the union of $n$-simplices with $a_i$, but that is not what we want,

Comment: this komplex would 'forget' the values of the coefficients $a_i$ and so we lose control over $[\beta]$. I could imagine that your suggestion could work for special case where all coefficnets $a_i$ are ones or zeroes.

Comment: Not quite, it is true that you can construct a complex $K$ with a homology class $[K]$ and a map $K\rightarrow X$ pushing forward $[K]$ to $[\beta]$. You take an $n$-simplex $\Delta_{ij}^n$ with $j$ ranging from $1$ to $|a_i|$ and then glue them together along their boundaries in a way to make the maps $\sigma_i^n$ glue to a map $K\rightarrow X$, which is possible by expanding out $\partial(\sum_ia_i\sigma_i^n)=0$. However, I think this construction and then coning off $K$ actually kills more homology than we might desire, so this is a suboptimal suggestion.

Comment: @Thorgott: that's interesting, I think I haven't seen such construction before. (even if this not solves the original problem properly, this might provide a  pave how to proceed) Let me try to rephrase it: so we start with a $n$-cycle $\beta= \sum_{i} a_i \sigma_i^n \in C_n$ representing the homology class we want to kill. Then we construct firstly certain complex $K$. And our goal is construct a chain of $K$, which maps to $\beta$.

Comment: The whole data which 
assures that it is indeed mapped to $\beta$ is 'encoded' in the boundary/characteristic map
$K \to X$ itself, right? But construction itself I not fully understand. You consider
as the $n$-simplices $\Delta_{ij}$ indexed over pairs $ij$ where 
$j \in \{1,.., \vert a_i \vert \}$. What is thier role in the construction? 
sorry, if the question is stupid. Do I understand it correctly, that the complex $K$ - 
itself as geometric object - is in your construction the union of the $n$-simplices $\Delta_{ij}$ 
where $i$ ranges over $i$ with $a_i \neq 0$?

Comment: or do I missing the point?

Comment: The construction is somewhere in Hatcher's book. Instead of the ugly double indices, write $\beta=\sum_ia_i\sigma_i^n$ with each $a_i\in\{-1,1\}$ (and the $\sigma_i^n$ not necessarily distinct). The complex $K$ is obtained by gluing together copies $\Delta_i^n$ of the standard $n$-simplex over the same index set by identifying their faces according to how $\partial\beta=0$. There's actually some choice in how you pair up the edges, which I'm not sure if it affects the result. Even worse, I don't know if the homotopy type of $K$ only depends on $[\beta]$, so perhaps this isn't even canonical.